# Customer and Business database relationships

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to create a database design and need some help. Diagram is displayed below. The database is for an address book attached to a e commerce site. Its coded in php and uses a mysql database.

See my diagram below - I think I have solved my problem but I want to know **is this a good way to do it?**

This is what I would like to do:

A person -
They can be a customer (optional)
They can be an employee of a business (optional)

A business -
The can be a customer (optional)

The problem is that Im not sure how to do this as mysql doesn't like these relationships.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1417817/diagram.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1417817/diagram.png)

Comment: Is something missing from the image? For example, you are referring to an `address` but I don't see the table for it.

Comment: I have removed those tables and have only included the relevant tables. The relevant tables are Customer, Businesses and Persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never been a big fan of using "id" as a column name, but the relationships seem sound.  What do you mean when you say "MySQL doesn't like these relationships."?

Why don't you have a relationship between contacts.business_addr_rel and your businesses table?